# How to bind list object to thymeleaf form?

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

I am try to build this UI below with thymeleaf but it seems I cannot archive this. I want to show all the possible controls with it privileges. and bind the existing value of control privileges of group to the form. So how could I archive this. The problem when there is a new control and the group have no value of control and privileges in the database.

[image: Here is the UI I want t build:]

Here is my form object:

```
public class GroupForm implements Serializable {

    /** */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    public List<GroupControl> getControls() {
        return this.group.getControls();
    }

    ...
}
```

And here is the GroupControl:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class GroupControl implements Serializable {

    /** */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    /** identifier of control */
    private int controlId;
    
    private boolean canRead;
    
    private boolean canWrite;
    
    private boolean canUpdate;
    
    private boolean canDelete;
}
```

Comment: I have a good, healthy reationship with Spring/Thymeleaf but I hate "list-to-form-bindings" from the bottom of my heart. It is ugly and so frustration undynamic. I think you can solve the issue by adding a initialized GroupControl for every group without values in the db.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly is not working? It is unclear to me.

Comment: @Flocke yeah that’s right. I used to use your method too but it seems not good to me. That’s why I post this question to find a good solution. It seems that Thymeleaf doesn’t have any good solutions with “list-to-form-binding”

Comment: @Wim the problem is that my group has some controls with it privilege store in database. So whenever I have new control, I want to add the new control to existing group. So I want to build the UI to show the existing controls with privileges and the new control with privileges. So I have a good solution to do that in Thymeleaf.